# Walk away from an argument, but what if the person is wrong?

Tags: discussion, comments

I often see comment chains like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449797/will-a-string-initializer-somewhat-waste-memory/35450341#comment58597975_35449797) where two people get into an extended discussion, essentially spamming the thread. Often at least one person gets defensive, in this case that person claims the other user is "harping" on them. At that point, I would walk away from the discussion, but the issue is an unresolved debate with a potentially incorrect comment left visible for the whole world to see. Problems I have with that:

- There are two sides to every argument; whether or not somebody is wrong is a matter of opinion, no matter what "conventional wisdom" says
- Both are guilty of taking up space in the thread

If I flag this comment thread one of two things may happen: a moderator will send it to a blackhole ("Please take this to chat") or nuke it. However I feel like that's squashing an ant with a hammer. If somebody is wrong on the Internet, we certainly want to correct them so they don't continue to perpetuate wrong information, as well as inform readers/lurkers what is actually correct. But these types of corrections almost always lead to a flamewar in the comments. If it's hidden in a chat, nobody really benefits - it's just hiding the argument under the rug. This problem is exacerbated in tags like [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) where bad comments are left on questions and there is not enough effort in the world to correct these people.

Is there a middle ground that can be taken between these two positions?

Comment: I don't see anyone getting angry or excessively defensive in the linked comment exchange. Tom isn't accusing Lundin of harping *on him*, but of harping on a singular comment that he made, causing the larger point to be missed. It would be sort of nice to have that information contained in the answers to a question, but I don't really think those comments are hurting anything.

Comment: I just fail to see an actual problem here. The existence of the comments system allows for chats to erupt, that's just the way it is. Nobody is getting hurt, just leave it be and move along. There are far more damaging things happening on SO that need all the attention.

Comment: Meh, just a "spirited" technical debate, no feelings are being hurt.  Pretty standard in the [c] and [c++] tags, you are never allowed to talk about implementation details because their standards strongly avoid nailing them down.  If you do anyway then there's always an SO user around to warn you that you are not allowed to assume anything.  You can flag a moderator to ask for a comment clean-up.  Not so sure they will unless it gets nasty, users do think these debates are useful.

Comment: 'Is there a middle ground that can be taken between these two positions?', yes.  I am right and the other poster backs down because they're wrong :)

Comment: I actually enjoy arguing with the cargo-culters who have never actually writen any commercial software, eg:  "You must always gracefully terminate threads and join() with them before leaving main()", and "You must always explicitly clean up all resources that you allocated before terminating your process".

Comment: 'but what if the person is wrong?' - what do you do if they're both wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of possible scenarios here:

The first is that one of the two parties is just hopelessly stubborn or being irrelevantly pedantic. There *is* a right answer, or at least a commonly-accepted guideline that should be followed without a specific justification to do otherwise. As such, this kind of extended discussion is unlikely to help anyone else in the future, and therefore you're right about those comments just taking up space. In cases like this, it's correct to flag a moderator to blow away the comments or move them to chat. Hey, if two people want to [argue on the Internet](https://xkcd.com/386/), far be it for us to try and stop them.

The other possibility is that there is a useful discussion going on, with important information being exchanged. That is the kind of thing you should be rightfully hesitant to ask for its deletion (or exile to chat where no one will ever see it). In this case, there are two good options:

1. Leave the constructive comments that are actually discussing the *issue* alone, and flag the irrelevant, personal-attack comments for obliteration. In other words, see where the "flamewar" started, and put out that flame with a direct blast of the hose. Avoid flooding the rest of the house.
2. If it is really one of those rare situations where *both* people are right, or there is really no right answer<sup>*</sup>, then a new question should be asked about that issue. You can ask the question and point the arguers to it, or you can advise one of them to ask the question. Either way, get the question asked. Why? This moves the discussion into a more appropriate place, where each party can lay out their argument(s) for why they are correct, the community can establish consensus by voting on the answers, and everyone can benefit from the insights exchanged from now until perpetuity.

<sub>* You claim in the question that *"There are two sides to every argument; whether or not somebody is wrong is a matter of opinion, no matter what "conventional wisdom" says*". I disagree with that in general. Of course there are two sides to any argument; in fact, there are as many sides as people participating in the debate. But that doesn't make all arguments equally valid. Plenty of arguments are just wrong, especially in technical fields.</sub>

Comment: If we were to argue about that last point who would be correct? Who is more pedantic in an argument about pedantry? Will Captchas ever be erased from the Internet? I find it highly ironic that the [tag:language-lawyer] tag, which is meant to encourage excessive pedantry, fuels pedantic arguments. When it comes to standards interpretation, what's "correct" is a matter of consensus (see any discussion regarding undefined behavior, that causes a lot of flamewars).